# how to save FormBean values in List & Iterate over JSP

Tags: struts

I want to save FormBean values in List, wants to save it in Session and again wants to iterate list for different FormBean values over JSP using `<logic:iterate>`.
I am able to iterate list or FormBean values `<logic:iterate>` but not able to do it with combination of both.

I have tried for this eg.

```
<table width="75%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"> 
  <logic:iterate id="myId" name="sessionData" property="getInsuredPhoneList"> 
  <tr> 
    <td width="25%"> <bean:write name="myId"/> </td> 
  </tr> 
  </logic:iterate> 
</table>`
```

Action class for showing JSP:

```
List<String> getInsuredPhoneList = new ArrayList<String>();
getInsuredPhoneList.add("");
getInsuredPhoneList.add("");
getInsuredPhoneList.add("");
getInsuredPhoneList.add("");
getInsuredPhoneList.add("");
sessionData.setGetInsuredPhoneList(getInsuredPhoneList);
```

Action class for processing JSP:

```
InsuredPhoneFormBean partyForm1=(InsuredPhoneFormBean)actionForm;
String type=partyForm1.getPhoneTypeCode();
String area=partyForm1.getAreaCode();
String landlineNumber=partyForm1.getLandlineNumber();
String mobileNumber=partyForm1.getMobileNumber();
String email=partyForm1.getEmailAddress();          
SessionData sessionData=getSessionData(request);
List<String> getInsuredPhoneList = new ArrayList<String>();
getInsuredPhoneList.add(type);
getInsuredPhoneList.add(area);
getInsuredPhoneList.add(landlineNumber);
getInsuredPhoneList.add(mobileNumber);
getInsuredPhoneList.add(email);
sessionData.setGetInsuredPhoneList(getInsuredPhoneList);
```

My Output is:

> Residential 9988009988 abc@gmail.com

I want here is `getInsuredPhoneList` will save multiple instances of FormBean values (`Residential 9988009988 abc@gmail.com`, `Office 9970009988 xyz@yahoo.com` ) and i want to iterate it through `getInsuredPhoneList`,
Such that

```
<table>
 <logic:iterate id="myId" name="sessionData" property="getInsuredPhoneList"> 
  <tr> 
    <td width="25%"> <bean:write name="myId" property="abc"/> </td> 
  </tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td width="25%"> <bean:write name="myId" property="xyz"/> </td> 
  </tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td width="25%"> <bean:write name="myId" property="pqr"/> </td>
  </tr>
 </logic:iterate> 
</table>
```

(property="pqr" means One of the property of FormBean)
and Output Like:
`Residential 9988009988 abc@gmail.com`
`Office 9970009988 xyz@yahoo.com`

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I have tried below eg. `<table width="75%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"> <logic:iterate id="myId" name="sessionData" property="getInsuredPhoneList"> <tr> <td width="25%"> <bean:write name="myId"/> </td> </tr> </logic:iterate> </table>`

Comment: update your answer with your code so it is easier for us to read it

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I have update quetion with output and where i am facing problem

Answer (score 0):

You code is so messed up that I can't really follow and understand exactly what you are asking. But this is the general concept:

1) Populate Objects and add them to List in Action Class(Suppose you have an Object `Contacts` that has 3 properties - office, tel, mail)

```
//in Action class  
Contacts myContact = new Contacts();
myContact.setOffice("office1");
myContact.setTel("123454");
myContact.setMail("xx@xx.com");

List<Contacts> myList = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
myList.add(myContact);
//You can add more Objects to List here
```

2) Set the list Object in `request` so you can access it in the JSP later

```
request.setAttribute("PHONE_LIST",myList);
```

3) In JSP you have to get the List from the `request` and iterate over it to show results

```
//in JSP
<table>  
 <logic: iterate id="dataObject" name="myForm" property="PHONE_LIST">  
 <tr>  
   <td><bean: write name="dataObject" property="office" /></td>  
   <td><bean: write name="dataObject" property="tel" /></td>  
   <td><bean: write name="dataObject" property="mail" /></td>  
 </tr>  
 </logic: iterate>  
</table>
```

Hope this helps